# how to use get_object_or_404 with order_by('?') to get random image

Tags: python, django

I want to get random object from model but if there are no data in database I want to return 404 page.

This line of code works for me well:

```
    dummy_image=DummyImage.objects.order_by('?').first().image_url.url
```

but I want to use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut.

So I tried this:

```
dummy_image = get_object_or_404(DummyImage).order('?').first().image_url.url
```

but it dosent't work and causes issues. It says that it returned more than two objects.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `get_object_or_404` shortcut uses `get()`, so it will raise an error if the filtered queryset returns more than one object.

You could slice the queryset to limit it to one object:

```
dummy_image = get_object_or_404(DummyImage.objects.order_by('?')[:1]).image_url.url
```

Alternatively, you could raise the `Http404` exception manually. This code is a bit longer but you might find it clearer what is going on.

```
from django.http import Http404

dummy_image = DummyImage.objects.order_by('?').first()
if dummy_image is None:
    raise Http404
else:
    dummy_image = dummy_image.image_url.url
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `get_object_or_404()` or `get_list_or_404()` u can change class Meta in models.py for ordering:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

   
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

When you render template u can seen needed ordering elements.